# How to run a yacc file on windows

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, yacc, lex

I have never seen a YACC file and this is my first encounter a YACC program. My teacher gave me this program for an infix to prefix compiler but I don't even know how to run it. I am new to compilers so please explain it simply. I have tried googling it but i don't understand anything.

I just want to know how should I run the program I don't need to know what each and every line does because I know what the program does in general and that was the point but I want to see it work myself

file `in.l`

```
/****************************************************/
* Problem Statement :- 
 Assignment To check whether given expression is 
 infix, postfix or prefix.
* Roll No :- 40 Batch :- A2
* BE(Computer)
* Date :- 2/09/2011
********************** in.l ***********************
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include"y.tab.h"
#include<math.h>
%}
%%
[0-9] {yylval.dval=atoi(yytext);return NUM;}
[t];
n return 0;
. {return yytext[0];}
%%
void yyerror(char * str)
{
 printf("n Invalid Expression...");
}
int main()
{
 printf("n ENter Expression => ");
 yyparse();
 return(0);
}
```

file `in.y`

```
********************** in.y ***********************
%{
#include<stdio.h>
int yylex(void);
%}
%union
{
 float dval;
}
%token <dval> NUMBER
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%nonassoc UMINUS
%type <dval> exp
%%
state : exp {printf("n Infix Expression...");}
 ;
exp : NUMBER
 | exp '+' exp {}
 | exp '-' exp {}
 | exp '*' exp {}
 | exp '/' exp {}
 ;
%%
```

file `pre.y`

```
********************** pre.y ***********************
%{
#include<stdio.h>
int yylex(void);
%}
%union
{
 int dval;
}
%token <dval> NUMBER
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%nonassoc UMINUS
%type <dval> exp
%%
state : exp {printf("n Prefix Expression...");}
 ;
exp : NUMBER
 | '+' exp exp {}
 | '-' exp exp {}
 | '*' exp exp {}
 | '/' exp exp {}
 ;
%%
```

file `post.y`

```
********************** post.y ***********************
%{
#include<stdio.h>
int yylex(void);
%}
%union
{
 int dval;
}
%token <dval> NUMBER
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%nonassoc UMINUS
%type <dval> exp
%%
state : exp {printf("n Postfix Expression...");}
 ;
exp : NUMBER
 | exp exp '+' {}
 | exp exp '-' {}
 | exp exp '*' {}
 | exp exp '/' {}
 ;
%%
```

Build, run, input and output

```
********************** Output ***********************
[a40@localhost ~]$ lex in.l
[a40@localhost ~]$ yacc -d in.y
[a40@localhost ~]$ cc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -ll
[a40@localhost ~]$ ./a.out

Enter Expression => 1+7
 Infix Expression...
[a40@localhost ~]$ ./a.out

Enter Expression => 1++7
 Invalid Expression...

[a40@localhost ~]$ lex in.l
[a40@localhost ~]$ yacc -d pre.y
[a40@localhost ~]$ cc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -ll
[a40@localhost ~]$ ./a.out

Enter Expression => 1+7
 Invalid Expression...
[a40@localhost ~]$ ./a.out

Enter Expression => +17
 Prefix Expression...

[a40@localhost ~]$ lex in.l
[a40@localhost ~]$ yacc -d pre.y
[a40@localhost ~]$ cc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -ll
[a40@localhost ~]$ ./a.out

Enter Expression => 12+34*-
 Postfix Expression...
[a40@localhost ~]$ ./a.out

Enter Expression => +17
 Invalid Expression...
```

Comment: Your question includes examples of lex and yacc being run at the bottom of that big quoted block

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Do you get an error message when you try the build commands shown below `********************** Output ***********************`? If yes, copy&paste the command(s) and the corresponding error message(s). If the problem is that you don't have or find `lex` and `yacc` for Windows, look for `flex` and `bison`.

Answer (score -3):

Case 1 : Only lex Programs need to be run and built and executed

Click on Execute CMD directly button in the IDE.

Compile the Lex File by typing the command lex .l

Build the Lex File by gcc/cc command in the CMD e.g gcc lex.yy.c -o

Execute the program by typing .exe

The -o   parameter is optional, you can skip the said parameter by directly building by gcc lex.yy.c
and then directly execute your program by typing a.exe

Case 2 : Both Lex and Yacc Programs together have to be linked and Compiled – Executed

Click on the Execute CMD button in the IDE.

Compile Yacc file by typing command yacc -dy <filename.y>

Compile the Lex File by typing the command lex .l

Build the Lex File by gcc/cc command in the CMD e.g gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -o

Execute the program by typing .exe

The -o   parameter is optional, you can skip the said parameter by directly building by gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c
and then directly execute your program by typing a.exe

Comment: What IDE do you think the OP has since they've not mentioned one